# Why is previously prohibited library references possible in ADT 12.0.0?

Tags: android, adt

Create android library project A, mark as library.
Create android library project B, mark as library.
Press button Android>Library>Add, and add reference to project A from project B.

**Previously this has been prohibited by eclipse/ADT.** I'm using ADT v12.0.0.
It should not be possible to reference another library project, as described in
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html
"Note that a library project cannot itself reference another library project"

**Is this

an undocumented feature of the ADT or

am I missing something obvious ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is outdated. Latest version of ADT and Android build system both support nested library dependencies. For more details about android libraries see my [blogpost](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/), *"Multiple Android Library dependencies"* section.